# rowset.jar WAS 5.1problem in WAS 6.1

Tags: java, websphere, rowset

currently I'm running my application under WAS 5.1 with rowset.jar working fine, but when upgrade server to 6.1, getting error with rowset.jar as below

java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: (javax/sql/rowset/CachedRowSet) bad major version at offset=6

do anyone face the same problem, how to solve this i try to with different version of jar but not solve,

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error indicates that the `javax/sql/rowset/CachedRowSet` class you are trying to use was compiled to Java 6 bytecode.

As far as I know, WAS 6.1 uses a Java 5 runtime:

E.g., for WAS 6.1 JVM:

```
> java -version
java version "1.5.0"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build pwi32devifx-20080907 (SR8a + IZ29767 + IZ30684 + IZ31214 + IZ31213))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.3, J2RE 1.5.0 IBM J9 2.3 Windows XP x86-32 j9vmwi3223ifx-20080811 (JIT enabled)
J9VM - 20080809_21892_lHdSMr
JIT  - 20080620_1845_r8
GC   - 200806_19)
JCL  - 20080907
```

So you need to find out why you are using a Java 6 compiled version of rowset, and change to Java 5.

Again, as far as I know, WAS 6.1 comes with the javax/sql/rowset/CachedRowSet class, so you shouldn't need to bundle it yourself.